# Can not load contact page

Tags: php

This is index file for my website. I want to load contact page but it doesn't work. How can I do with my code. Thank you

```
<?php 
$Page = (isset($_GET["p"]));

include('includes/header.php');

if ($Page == "contact"){
    include('pages/contact.php');
} else {
    include('pages/home.php');
}

include('includes/footer.php');?>
```

Comment: what you mean with "it doesn't work"?

Comment: ``isset`` returns a **boolean** value. Thus ``isset($_GET["p"])`` will return true or false, NOT the **contact** what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

`isset` results a boolean value, so `$Page` would be `true`

Try this: `$Page = isset($_GET["p"]) ? $_GET["p"] : null;`
Or
`$Page = $_GET["p"] ?? null;`